# python MySQLdb godaddy.com hosting

Tags: python

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd', 'sampledb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (110)")
```

How do I connect and what is the issue here? Thank you!

Comment: This is something you should contact GoDaddy about.

Comment: Maybe you don't have MySQL running - but this is a localized question as there are many unknowns like what environment you're in, what the server has installed. Check to make sure you have mysql installed, and that it's actually running.

Comment: is your problem solved ??

Answer (score 3):

You do not connect to a database on localhost on Go Daddy shared hosting.  You will need to locate the correct database host.

1. Log in to your Account Manager.
2. Click Web Hosting.
3. Next to the hosting account you want to use, click Launch.
4. In the Databases section of the Hosting Control Center, click the MySQL icon.
5. Click the pencil icon next to the database you would like to get connection strings for.

Your database host name displays in the Host Name field.  It will end with "hostedresource.com".

Answer (score 1):

See godaddy's help pages:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/39

Answer (score 0):

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect("host", "user", "password", "database")
```

**host**: Get in cPanel "Web sites IP".

[image]

**user**: This user must to have permissions to access (You can add this permission in *MySQL Databases* menu in cPanel).
**database**: Name database.

**Note**: Add permission for your IP in *Remote MySQL* Menu in cPanel

You can use sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@host/database')
conn = engine.connect()
```